# DTS is not declared SSIS 2008 VB.Net script task

Tags: vbscript, ssis

I have the script below that will take a .gz file and decompress it. However whenever I try to utilise this code I can't get the script to verify.

Error message - Name Dts is not declared.

Is anyone able to help with this please? I rarely use script tasks in SSIS.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO.Compression
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime

'''<summary>Decompress file</summary>

Public Class ScriptMain
    Public Sub Main()
        Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success
        Dim success As Boolean = True
        Dim workFilePath As String
        workFilePath = Dts.Variables("User::sBloombergReplyFileFullPathUR0L").Value.ToString()
        If File.Exists(workFilePath) Then
            If Not workFilePath.EndsWith(".gz") Then
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "", workFilePath + " is not compressed; skipping decompression", Nothing, -1, True)
                Return
            End If
            Dim uncompressedFileName As String
            Dim bytes(Int16.MaxValue) As Byte
            Dim n As Integer = 1
            Try
                uncompressedFileName = workFilePath.Substring(0, workFilePath.Length - 3)
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "", "decompressing " + workFilePath + " to " + uncompressedFileName, Nothing, -1, True)
                Using writer As New FileStream(uncompressedFileName, FileMode.Create)
                    Using compressedStream As Stream = File.Open(workFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
                        Using unzipper As New GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress)
                            Do Until n = 0
                                n = unzipper.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
                                writer.Write(bytes, 0, n)
                            Loop
                            unzipper.Close()
                        End Using
                        compressedStream.Close()
                    End Using
                    writer.Close()
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                Dts.Events.FireError(0, ex.TargetSite().ToString(), "Unable to decompress " + workFilePath + "; " + ex.Message, Nothing, -1)
                success = False
            Finally
                If success = False And File.Exists(uncompressedFileName) Then
                    Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Failure
                    File.Delete(uncompressedFileName)
                End If
            End Try
        Else
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, "", workFilePath + " does not exist", Nothing, -1)
            Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Failure
            Return
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Dts is unknown in your class. You broke your inheritance because `ScriptMain` no longer extends `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase`

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO.Compression
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime

<System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version:="1.0", Publisher:="", Description:="")> _
<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)> _
Partial Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase

    Public Sub Main()
        Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success
        Dim success As Boolean = True
        Dim workFilePath As String
        workFilePath = Dts.Variables("User::sBloombergReplyFileFullPathUR0L").Value.ToString()
        If File.Exists(workFilePath) Then
            If Not workFilePath.EndsWith(".gz") Then
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "", workFilePath + " is not compressed; skipping decompression", Nothing, -1, True)
                Return
            End If
            Dim uncompressedFileName As String
            Dim bytes(Int16.MaxValue) As Byte
            Dim n As Integer = 1
            Try
                uncompressedFileName = workFilePath.Substring(0, workFilePath.Length - 3)
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "", "decompressing " + workFilePath + " to " + uncompressedFileName, Nothing, -1, True)
                Using writer As New FileStream(uncompressedFileName, FileMode.Create)
                    Using compressedStream As Stream = File.Open(workFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
                        Using unzipper As New GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress)
                            Do Until n = 0
                                n = unzipper.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
                                writer.Write(bytes, 0, n)
                            Loop
                            unzipper.Close()
                        End Using
                        compressedStream.Close()
                    End Using
                    writer.Close()
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                Dts.Events.FireError(0, ex.TargetSite().ToString(), "Unable to decompress " + workFilePath + "; " + ex.Message, Nothing, -1)
                success = False
            Finally
                If success = False And File.Exists(uncompressedFileName) Then
                    Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Failure
                    File.Delete(uncompressedFileName)
                End If
            End Try
        Else
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, "", workFilePath + " does not exist", Nothing, -1)
            Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Failure
            Return
        End If
    End Sub

    Enum ScriptResults
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    End Enum
End Class
```

Comment: No problem and welcome to SO. If you find answers helpful, feel free to click the Up arrow and if this has resolved your problem, click the green check mark.

Comment: Downvoter, (hi [@TheOptimusPrime](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2517150/theoptimusprimus)) could you help me understand the downvote so that I may improve this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using a Script Component? As already pointed out here: [Connection Manager in Script Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403454/connection-manager-in-script-component) there is a difference between *Script Task* and *Script Component* (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/comparing-the-script-task-and-the-script-component?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16)

`Dts` property is a member of the `ScriptMain` class in Script Tasks while Script Components does not have access to a Dts property. So in Script Components the way of accessing SSIS resources is different (as you can see in the linked Microsoft documentation)